# New BrowserWindow URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, quasar-framework

I would like to create 2 browserwindows.

1st one will be pointing to localhost
2nd one I want to point URL to a Vue component (since there are no actual .html file for this project - only using Vue to render the page).

Currently I have something like this, but doesnt work. 
How can I use a Vue component path (ie Debug.vue) as the pathname here?

```js
debugWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
    minWidth: 600,
    minHeight: 300,
    useContentSize: true,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});

let debugUrl = require('url').format({
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true,
    pathname: require('path').join(__dirname, 'pages/Debug.vue')
});

debugWindow.loadURL(debugUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want to achieve, you simply have to add a route to your router:

```
// src/router/routes.js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: 'my_special_path', component: () => import('pages/Debug.vue') }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then you can use it as

```js
debugWindow.loadURL('/my_special_path');
```

and it will point to `pages/Debug.vue` component (page).

Also, since it is debug page and you probably don't want your users to access it, you may want to have this route only for development purposes and strip it out of your application in production environment. You can do it this way:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      // your normal routes
    ]
  }
]

// routes only for development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    routes[0].children.push({ path: 'my_special_path', component: () => import('pages/Debug.vue') });
}
```

All examples here assume default quasar app template.